# Can not add images to iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, simulator, ios8.1

I can not add any images to ios simulator. I tried saving from google images and tried dragging the images to photos app in the simulator but no image appear in my photos app. There are only 5 sample images.

My iOS simulator is 8.1 and same problem in all simulators(iphone 6, 5s,4s)

Comment: Open an image in the simulator's safari ( drag and drop any image link on simulator ). Press long on the image. Save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/
```

…and add Dog.THM and Cat.JPG.

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

This might help you.

Comment: there is no iphone simulator folder in application support http://tinypic.com/r/2ibyblt/8

Comment: go to finder-> Go menu -> Go To Folder -> paste any of above link. ->OK

Comment: thanks for the answer. This method works. But the drag method only works in iOS 7.1 simulator for me

Answer (score 1):

Easies way is to drag the image from your computer and drop it on your simulator. There's no need to drop it to the photos app. It'll automatically add the image to the photos app.